# Adding static PDF file to nuxt js project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a project in vue and I want to build it with Nuxt.
I have link in footer that I want user to download a PDF file by clicking on it , it works fine on local server but when I build the project I can't find the pdf file . 
I stored the file in Static/documents folder

Comment: Does the file exist in the server?

Comment: No, I have it locally, I try building the project with Nuxt js but the pdf file does not include in Dist folder @bhavinjr

Comment: @bhavinjr I don't want to add the file to the server manually, I want it to be in the project files

Answer (score 6):

You have to put the .pdf in the static folder. Then to see you go to http://localhost:3000/yourpdf.pdf (localhost o your domain)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to push it the server ? How your are deploying your application ? using git ? if yes check if there is files in the stage with "git status" command
Did you try to access to yourdomain.com/documents/yourfile.pdf ?

Comment: No, the problem is when I build my project with Nuxt js it does not put the .pdf in the dist folder, I think I need to configure loader of webpack.